# make java multithread wait until input given

Tags: java, multithreading, input, wait

Im trying to make a simple code to simulate concurrent connection on a DB2 database using java. my current code looks a bit like this:

```
class TheThread implements Runnable{
@override
public void run(){
    //make the database connection
    //need to pause here until any button pressed
    //execute query to the database
}
}
```

the program will make few hundreds to thousands threads simultaneously, therefore I want to make sure all thread is connected before executing the query so it really are processed at the same time.

How can I do this?

Comment: when any button is pressed, all threads should start, or only one? If one, any one or some specific thread?

Comment: all of them, I managed to do so by using Cyclicbarrier. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CyclicBarrier from java.util.concurrent package

```
static CyclicBarrier b = new CyclicBarrier(nConnections);

public void run() {
    // make the database connection
    b.await();  //threads will stop here untill nConnections are opened
    ...
```

Comment: the cyclicbarrier will make all thread wait, until every thread arrived to the point of the barrier in each thread, and will continue automatically when all of them has reached the point, am I right? I need to make my code wait for user input, because it will be running on several machine to allow more concurrent connection made, and after the button is pressed, will start (almost) same time. is there a way to make it wait for input?

Comment: ---edit thank you, I've solved my problem using this solution. turn out that i only need to create one thread that wont come to the barrier until I pressed a button, how silly I am, Thank you my good sir